# Calculating z values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table, `gainfinal`, which consists of three columns: `countrycode`, `year` and `values`.

I want to calculate z values for all the rows. 
I did a simple query like this.

```
SELECT (
 `values` - STDDEV(  `values` )
) / AVG(  `values` ) AS zvalue
FROM  `gainfinal`
```

But the query returned only one row. How can I perform same thing for all the rows?

Comment: What are you trying to calculate the Z value for?  the unique country code, year, or something else?

Comment: It's for all the values.

Comment: Your formula for the z-score is incorrect.  You subtract the average and divide by the standard deviations.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to get the aggregated values:

```
SELECT (gf.`values` - stats.average) / stats.s AS zvalue
FROM  `gainfinal` gf cross join
      (select sttdev(values) as s, avg(values) as average from gainfinal) stats;
```

In most databases, your original query would generate an error, because it is mixing aggregated columns and non-aggregated columns in a query with no `group by`.  The solution is a separate subquery that does the calculation.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff. Thank you for your answer. But surprisingly, it didn't work for me. It says : Error #1064

Comment: @ShivaBhusal . . . It should work, particularly now that I put in the correct formula for the z-score.

Comment: Yaa. I checked the formula and corrected it. But still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @stdev AS FLOAT, @avg AS FLOAT

SELECT @stdev = STDEV([values]), @avg = AVG([values])
FROM gainfinal

SELECT 
    countrycode
    , year
    , [values]
    , ([values] - @stdev) / @avg AS zvalue
FROM gainfinal
```

Comment: This seemed interesting but it didn't work as well. :D